# IOS 9 Modal not working

Tags: angularjs, dialog, modal-dialog, ionic-framework, ios9

we are using Ionic framework for an app which runs on ipad device, We have recently migrated to IOS9, several things are not working, Modal dialogues box is not getting opened, it goes to login page which we have declared in otherwise.
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login')

The same thing works in IOS8

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/

Comment: empty href links <a href="#"> will trigger your otherwise state, so test those and remove the empty href if necessary. It worked

Comment: I have added the answer below so you can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/

> Also, empty href links `<a href="#">` will trigger your otherwise state, so test those and remove the empty href if necessary.